# Decoding Encrypted Query string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, query-string

I am using the method described in the following [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1330421/100283) and I am using the following code to encrypt:

```
'Page1.aspx    
Protected Sub butEncrypt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butEncrypt.Click
    Dim QueryString As String = "type=Int&pk=" & _primaryKey
    QueryString = Tools.encryptQueryString(QueryString)
    Response.Redirect(/SearchResults.aspx?Val=" & QueryString)
End Sub
```

and then finally de-encrypt:

```
        'SearchResults.aspx
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Not IsPostBack) Then
         If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request(CIAppGlobals.GlobalVar.Val)) Then
            Dim qs As String = Request.QueryString(CIAppGlobals.GlobalVar.Val)
            qs = Tools.decryptQueryString(qs)

            Dim Values As String() = qs.Split(CChar("&"))

            _imageType = String.Empty
            _primaryKey = 0

            For Each value As String In Values
               Dim data As String() = value.Split(CChar("="))

               Select Case data(0).ToUpper
                  Case "TYPE"
                     _imageType = data(1)
                  Case "PK"
                     _primaryKey = CInt(data(1))
               End Select
            Next
            Else
               _imageType = HttpContext.Current.Request("type")
               _primaryKey = CInt(HttpContext.Current.Request("pk"))
         End If
    End If
   End Sub
```

My question is should I being using a different method to extract the decoded query string values other than what I am doing? Thanks in advance for your constructive responses.

## Solution

After looking at Darin's response I have decided to incorporate it into my project, here is my updated code:

```
'Page1.aspx    
Protected Sub butEncrypt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butEncrypt.Click
  Dim query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty)
  query("type") = "Int"
  query("pk") = CStr(_primaryKey)

  Dim QueryString As String = Tools.encryptQueryString(query.ToString())
  Response.Redirect(/SearchResults.aspx?Val=" & QueryString)
End Sub
```

I still want to encrypt the query string because I want to prevent users from changing the Query String Values manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly building the query string in the first place. You are using string concatenations and not properly encoding them. What if `_primaryKey` contains a `&` or `=` characters? You could use the [ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) method to properly build a query string:

```
Dim query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty)
query("type") = "Int"
query("pk") = _primaryKey
Dim queryString = query.ToString()
```

The same method could be used for parsing the decoded query string:

```
Dim values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qs)
Dim type = query("type")
Dim primaryKey = query("pk")
' work with the type and primaryKey values
```

Never use string concatenations and splitting when dealing with urls. Always use the right tool for the right job.

That's as far as creating/parsing query strings is concerned. As far as encrypting/decryption the values is concerned, you haven't shown/told us anything about the `Tools` class that you are using so I cannot provide you with any constructive comments about it.

You know that the best encryption is to never send the actual value to the client. So you could store it in some backend storage on the server and then use an unique id in the url. This id could be used on the target page to fetch the original value. This way you don't need to be encrypting/decrypting anything.

Comment: Thanks for you response. The Tools class contains the two methods that I found in the link I referenced in my OP (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1330421/100283). I would like to store the value in a database but I am working with a legacy database so I am not able to make any new changes to it.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, but Type can only be one of five different values (Int, Sbj, Veh, Grp, and Bus) and _primaryKey is an integer value. So neither value would ever contain an & or an = character. I will add in your solution as it can't hurt.